# I try to make my Material-UI RaisedButton link to an external url without success?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui

As the question in the title state.

Playing with react, react-router and material-ui and in one place I want to make an action button in a Card component link to an external url, like
 without success.

I'm currently thinking of adding an event handler to use window.open, but it must be a smarter way?

I did find a solution, before the code looked like this.

```
<CardActions>
   <RaisedButton
       href={this.props.url}
       label="OK"
   />
</CardActions>
```

The solution was very simple:

```
<CardActions>
   <a href={this.props.url} target="_blank">
     <RaisedButton
        label="OK"
     />
   </a>
</CardActions>
```

Comment: It's better to paste code in the post, not an image.

Comment: Just checking all bases, did you make sure the value you're passing into the href is not null and contains the correct string?

Comment: Thnaks for you time and comments. I did solve it and I will try to post the solution pasting the code instead. :-)

Comment: You can answer your own question if you have a solution. It's ok.

Comment: out of curiousity, how did you come to post an image of your code? It seems like at least a couple of extra steps had to be made, both on the "back end" and the "front end". Ctrl+c ctrl+v with some tags, vs screen capture, save image, crop, upload, insert...

Comment: I have no idea. :-)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

If we are adding external link in react-router Link or material-ui Button then This is important we add 'http://' (or https://) in external url. link will not work without add http.

WRONG CODE -

```
<Link target="_blank" to='www.google.com'>Google</Link>
```

then redirect link will

```
localhost:3000/www.google.com
```

RIGHT CODE -

If we want to redirect with react-router Link then this is example code -

```
<Link target="_blank" to='http://www.google.com'>Google</Link>
```

If we want to redirect with material-ui Button then this is example code -

```
<Button target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com/">Google</Button>
```

**Note:** I added `target="_blank"` in Link/Button. This is optional (and If I will add any external link in my website then I will want to open that link in another Browser Tab not in same Tab.)

Comment: Don't forget you don't have to use "_blank". You can use a name to prevent opening a new tab/window every time the user clicks it, which can be very annoying. I.e. `target="mynewtab"`

Comment: What is the solution if I want to use to="mailto:test@test.com" ?

Answer (score 21):

You can wrap `<RaisedButton />` into `<Link />` component for internal routing.

```
<Link to={this.props.cardItem.resourceUrl}>
  <RaisedButton label="Ok" />
</Link>
```

And wrap into simple `<a>` tag for external:

```
<a href={this.props.cardItem.resourceUrl}>
  <RaisedButton label="Ok" />
</a>
```

Comment: Can I use external links with the <Link component, setting the target?

Comment: `<Link>` component is used for react routing. External links have nothing with it. For external links fill free to use `<a>`.

Answer (score 7):

You should use target, component, and href props

```
<Button                
   target="_blank"
   component="a"
   href="http://www.google.com/"
>
 Google
</Button>
```

Comment: i don't show target as a valid prop of button

Answer (score 3):

```
<Button component={Link} to={path} >
   LINK BUTTON
</Button>
```

Comment: It would be good if you can explain the code for future readers.

Comment: For me it worked with a change, I used "href" instead of "to":
<Button component={Link} href={path} > ...

Answer (score 0):

I tried using a `Link` in the `Button.component` prop - but it lead to the Button component to be full-width and trying to style it with `width: auto;` did nothing.

Anyway, long story short I was able to get this to work functionally and stylistically with:

```
      <Link href="/somewhere/over/the/rainbow" target="_blank">
        <Button size="medium" variant="contained" color="primary">
          View RV
        </Button>
      </Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

This still was buggy for me. The fix was to use `<a>` instead of react-router-dom's `<Link>`.